# Give equal width to controls inside a Stack Panel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-8, stackpanel

I need to have two `RadChart`s inside a horizontal `StackPanel` and want both the charts to be of equal width. I don't want to give explicit length to the width of the charts.  This can be easily achieved by using a `Grid` control but my scenario requires a `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them into individual `Grids`, use a column with a common [`SharedSizeGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) and set [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) to `true` on the `StackPanel`.

Comment: 1+ for the solution, though some sample markup would be perfect.

Comment: @HighCore: Redundant, enough of that in the documentation.

Comment: @sebesbal: That is true for a lot of basic things regarding WPF, the documentation for it is really good.

Answer (score 17):

Often the documentation is not quickly comprehensible because it is either written in a confusing way or the needed information is hidden among a ton of other information that doesn't help in the particular case. And so, in my opinion, even if it is a "basic thing", it doesn't hurt to give a quick answer (or if one thinks it is too primitive, he/she should just post nothing at all).

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySizeGroup" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Height="23" Content="Reset" Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySizeGroup" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Height="23" Content="Set" Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySizeGroup" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Height="23" Content="Import" Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySizeGroup" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Height="23" Content="Export" Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MySizeGroup" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Height="23" Content="Create new" Padding="5,1" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more,  yeah it's all in the documentation yeah fine but finding it is like looking for a needle in the haystack